# Submit pdf form fields to a HTTP POST request

Tags: javascript, pdf, forms, http-post, acrobat

I've made a pdf form in Adobe Acrobat. Now I want to make a button that submits the form to a HTTP POST request. I have searched for about 4 hours, but I have not found an example to do this.

Here I read that it is possible to send the pdf form fields with a HTTP submission, but there's also no example given:
http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/form-submit-e-mail-demystified

I'm looking for a JavaScript example that I can link to the submit button.

Comment: Are you trying to just submit the name/value pair for each field or the entire PDF?  The examples I've seen submit the entire PDF file back to the server.

Comment: Yes, only the name/value pair. It is unnecessary to submit the rest of the information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
doc.submitForm(url, false);
```

or

```
doc.submitForm( url, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null
                null, null, null, null, null, "HTML" );
```

`submitForm` actually takes 23 different parameters, the above is only using 16 of them.  And if I miscounted, I'm trying to use the cSubmitAs parameter.

This from the JavaScript API reference, which can be found at... lets see...  [right here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html).  Enjoy.

PS: "this" is almost universally the document in acrobat events.  event.target might be a field or something, but "this" is going to be the document.

PPS: Things like `bEmpty`, `aFields`, and various other parameters don't work when `bFDF = false`.

Comment: "...takes 23 different parameters" - wow, that is so, so, so, so,... ...so wrong.

Comment: It wasn't MY idea.  Allthough calling it with {url: url, cSubmitAs: "HTML"} would have been considerably less painful, in retrospect.

Comment: I recently tried to do this also, but the submit doesn't work with Foxit free PDF reader. It works fine with Acrobat free reader.

Comment: Script support outside of the Acrobat stuff is going to be spotty.  They tend to cover the basics fairly well, but anything off the beaten path is a crap shoot at best.

Comment: The bit of JSON in @MarkStorer's comment should be {cURL: url, cSubmitAs: "HTML"}.

Comment: Where does `doc` come from?

Comment: Instead of `doc`, I've had more success with a JS method on `this`.