# How to submit the form from an embedded PDF from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I am using [PDFObject](http://pdfobject.com/) to embed a PDF with form fields in a html page.

I would like to add a button to the page, which will cause acrobat to submit the fields back to the web server.  If I was doing this within the PDF, it would look [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346590/submit-pdf-form-fields-to-a-http-post-request)

Here is what I have so far, which throws an exception, because `pdf` does not contain a property called `doc`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var pdf = new PDFObject({ url: "test.pdf" }).embed("pdf");

            $("#savebutton").button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-disk" }, text: true, label: "Save" });

            $("#saveButton").click(function () {
                pdf.doc.submitForm("submiturl", false);
            });
        });
```

So the crux of the question, how do I get access to the "doc" object within the pdf's DOM, from the page.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to interact with an embedded pdf is using `.postMessage()`, e.g.

```
var pdf = document.getElementById("PDFObj");
pdf.postMessage([message]);
```

Then you need some JavaScript in the PDF (yes, you can do that, but [have fun figuring it out](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf)) to catch it.