# How to edit file in client browser and then send it back to server

Tags: java, pdf, object, embed

I am building a application in which user has to fill the pdf form and has to send it back to server.

I was hoping it to do it with object HTML tag. But i dont know how to send that edited document back to server without saving that document to client machine.

Is this possible?

Comment: @AVD No actually i have a pdf form which need to be filled by user. So was using embed/object tag to make it available on webpage only.

Comment: Got it! Take a look at SO thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346590/submit-pdf-form-fields-to-a-http-post-request

Comment: FDF support require a bit more server side.

Comment: thanks AVD and RAVN...m using Javascript now in PDF to update document on server.. thanks again!! :)