# How to Submit PDF form using javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

Can we submit PDF FORM using javascript? 
If yes please let me know how I can achieve this.

Comment: you got code already done? at least something ?

Comment: I didn't got any code. I was wondering about the possibility of this functionality. Actually I am waiting for such PDF form file, so I thought, if I get any answer or guideline, I will start working on it in right way as soon as I receive a PDF file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can submit PDF forms using javascript. Here is a thread discussing this issue:

[Submit pdf form fields to a HTTP POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346590/submit-pdf-form-fields-to-a-http-post-request)

Comment: I might have asked question in wrong way.. sorry if so.
Is it possible to submit PDF form using EXTERNAL javascript?
I guess solution of above question is achieved by adding javascript in PDF.