# Collect data on web on submit of PDF

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, pdf

I  have a pdf on website, which i want, client download it or i will email them and they fill it, and when they click on submit button in the pdf, it send all the form field data to my webpage, so i can enter all the information on my database.

My Webpage using ASP.net as server side language

I have created a pdf by using "Nitro PDF" in nitro pdf there is a option to Submit form on click as a FDF,XFDF,html.

I have tried html but that doesn't work , so i collect all the fields information by using  javascript an send information via GET method, mentioned below

```
// Obtain the value from the first field
var Fname = getField("firstName").value;

// Obtain the value from the second field
var Mname = getField("middleName").value;

// Obtain the value from the third field
var Lname = getField("lastName").value;

app.launchURL("http://techchef.org/test.php?Fname="+Fname+"&Lname="+Lname, true);
```

but the problem in the above mention method is, i have more than 48 fields & cant use GET method..

so i try to find out the POST method in javascript which can be workable in the pdf and i tried the below mention code which i found from this link [Submit pdf form fields to a HTTP POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346590/submit-pdf-form-fields-to-a-http-post-request) but it doesn't work...It only send empty information

**Code For POST Method**
    app.submitForm("http://example.com/test.php, true);

then i research about FDF, and i found FDF Kit, but when try this i found it only works if i ask user to fill the form of the pdf with out downloading..So in this way i can not able to send the pdf to the clients via email.

**Please guide me how can i receive the filled data on my webpage on the click of "send" button (please advice if i can use a POST method or some thing else)**